# ISATAP configuration not working when adding hosts

Tags: cisco, routing, ipv6, tunnel, ipv6-transition

I am trying to make an ISATAP configuration where two ipv6 hosts connected to dual stacked routers can communicate to each other.

I have the following configuration: [image: config]

I have configured RIP across the IPV4 network, configured ISATAP tunnels and configured static routing where every packet that arrives an edge router with a host in it's destination will be forwarded to the host.

R1 and R3 seems to be communicating well (pinging to the ipv6 interface works).

the configuration for R1 is:

```
interface Tunnel 1
no ip address
no ip redirects
ipv6 address 133::/64 eui-64
tunnel source 10.0.1.1
tunnel mode ipv6ip isatap
exit

interface FastEthernet0/0
ip address 10.0.1.1 255.255.255.0
no shutdown
exit

interface FastEthernet0/1
no ip address
no shutdown
ipv6 address 2001::1/64 
exit

ipv6 route 2003::/64 133::5EFE:A00:301
ipv6 route 2001::2/64 FastEthernet0/1
exit
```

and for R2:

```
interface Tunnel 1
no ip address
no ip redirects
ipv6 address 133::/64 eui-64
tunnel source 10.0.3.1
tunnel mode ipv6ip isatap
exit

interface FastEthernet0/0
ip address 10.0.3.1 255.255.255.0
no shutdown
exit

interface FastEthernet0/1
no ip address
no shutdown
ipv6 address 2003::1/64 
exit

ipv6 route 2001::/64 133::5EFE:A00:101
ipv6 route 2003::2/64 FastEthernet0/1
exit
```

**Router model is cisco c375

Thanks

Comment: You should include the full router configurations, and the route tables.

Comment: The second IPv6 route statement on each router is unnecessary, and you should remove it. You do not need an explicit route to a directly connected network, and you could actually cause problems with it.

Comment: The first IPv6 route cannot be correct because those are not EUI-64 addresses for the interface addresses, and you have the tunnel using EUI-64 addressing. You should explicitly address the tunnel, and you should use IPv6 `/127` addressing for a point-to-point link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solved,
Problem was not enabling ipv6 unicast routing.
this can be done by using: `ipv6 unicast-routing`.